# TypeScript now returning error on interface

Tags: typescript

In my `config.test.json` I have:

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "user1",
    "database": "db1"
  },
  "production": {
    "username": "user2",
    "database": "db2"
  }
},
"SEED": true
```

Then in `index.ts` I have an interface:

```
interface IConfigDB {
    username: string;
    database: string;
    otherProp: number;
}
```

And the actual `configDB` object:

```
const configDB: IConfigDB = {
    ...config[process.env.NODE_ENV],
    otherProp: false,
};
```

As you see `otherProp` is p `false`, while it should be a number. But my TypeScript is not complaining about that. On the other hand, on the typescript sandbox, mocking `config.test.json` as an object, it works as expected —[here the sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgUwG4IDYgA4FsFlgXhgG8AoGGAVwgQCcwBDHALhgCIraBGVgGjPnpR6AI3rUWrOMO4kAvgG4SJAJZ5aAM3rAEMAJIB5YQCsEwKAEFi-DnUYIW0GqoDmi8nEEix9mI5duYECgAC1oABRpMFmEQEFQEejBFWSVQSFg09WVnABEAIRYDY1MLGEJScgA6asQUdGxcKD5yINCaCKiYTjlFIA)—:

```
const development = {
  username: "user1",
  database: "db1"
};

interface IObjectA {
  username: string;
  database: string;
  otherProp: boolean;
}

const configDB: IObjectA = {
  ...development,
  otherProp: 1
};

// (property) IObjectA.otherProp: boolean
// Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
// Quick Fix...
// Peek Problem
```

Here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "target": "es5",
        "allowJs": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "noEmit": true
    },
    "include": ["src"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Does anyone know what is going on here?

---

Edit:

If I add `"strict": true` to the `tsconfig.json`, then on

```
const configDB: IConfigDB = {
    ...config[process.env.NODE_ENV],
    operatorsAliases: false,
};
```

I get this error:

```
(property) NodeJS.Process.env: NodeJS.ProcessEnv
Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type.ts(2538)
```

Any idea?

--
Edit2:

As @lukasgeiter pointed out, the type for `...config[process.env.NODE_ENV]` is `string | undefined`, which is why it is complaining. Adding `!` will tell TypeScript that there is value… but.

Now the error on:

```
...config[process.env.NODE_ENV!],
```

is:

[image]

Which says something like in my `config.test.json` there are no types, or something like that.

Not sure what it means…

Comment: Sounds like your compiler options might be less strict than those on the playground. Please update the question with your `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: @lukasgeiter updated!

Comment: The error you got is because `process.env.NODE_ENV` is typed as `string | undefined` and `undefined` can't be used as index signature. You can tell the compiler that you're sure it's not `undefined` by adding an exclamation mark after `NODE_ENV` like this: `config[process.env.NODE_ENV!]`.
I have a feeling though that this won't resolve your problem fully. If that happens to be the case, please let me know what the exact type of `config` is.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now the error is a different, I'll update the question : )

Comment: I will ask a new question, will be cleaner!

Comment: It's fine, I'm already writing up the answer.

Comment: Great, thats awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright let's go through this step by step:

### 1. No errors?

As you've discovered, by default TypeScript quite for giving. It's only when we turn on `strict` that we notice something is not exactly how it should be. Especially when developing new applications I highly recommend to always enable strict mode.

### 2. `NODE_ENV` could be undefined

The next problem, or the first real issue is that `process.env` is typed as:

```js
interface ProcessEnv {
    [key: string]: string | undefined;
}
```

So `process.env.NODE_ENV` could be a string or `undefined`. But (at least in strict mode) variables of type `undefined` cannot be used as index.

A solution for this is to mark it as defined using the [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) `!`:

```js
...config[process.env.NODE_ENV!]
```

### 3. Possible index values

The compiler knows that the `config` object has exactly two properties: `'development'` and `'production'`. But `process.env.NODE_ENV!` has the type `string`. Of course this includes `'development'` and `'production'`, but also any other possible string value.

One solution for this would be to cast `NODE_ENV` to a matching type:

```js
...config[process.env.NODE_ENV as 'development' | 'production']
```

Or a bit more elegant, extract it into a new variable:

```js
const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV as 'development' | 'production';
// ...
...config[NODE_ENV]
```

You could even do this more dynamic by reading all keys of the type of `config`:

```js
const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV as keyof typeof config;
```

> **Note:** All these casting approaches don't guarantee that the value of `NODE_ENV` will actually be `development` or `production`. You might want to add a runtime check and appropriate fallback in case it's not set or has an invalid value.

Comment: Makes sense, but I have to read this carefully. Tons of thanks!